# fast double multiplication with integer precision

Tags: c++

What is the fastest way to multiply two double numbers with lesser precision (eg Int precision)? Will it be faster when I use:

```
double a = 2.2;
double b = 3.2;
int c = int(a)*int(b);
```

or is there a faster way?

edit:
Seams like converting to integer precision was a bad idea. 
I'll try to explain my problem better:

I have a set of double data and i need to extract some properties from it what mainly involves a lot of multiplication. Now I am trying to decrease the calculation time by reducing the calculation precision. Will maybe this:

```
double a = 2.2;
double b = 3.2;
float c = float(a)*float(b);
```

work better than integer conversion ?

Comment: I think these might give you two different answers. `int(a*b)` will first give you 7.04 and then truncate to 7. `int(a) * int(b)` will be `2 * 3` or 6. Which answer do you want?

Comment: The difference between the answers is irrelevant for me. I am only interested in the fast multiplication.

Comment: This operation is unlikely to be your bottleneck.

Comment: If you don't care about the result that much, why even have doubles?

Comment: keep in mind that converting between int and double also takes time. and double precision isn't necessarily slower than integer.

Comment: @crashmstr i need the doubles as doubles later on,  but not for this multiplication

Comment: both double and int multiplication is very fast. They are executed on different cpu units.

Comment: I've amended my answer with a benchmar for the float version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int(a)*int(b); a 1,000,000,000 times:

real    0m4.946s
user    0m4.852s
sys 0m0.018s

int(a*b); a 1,000,000,000 times:

real    0m4.067s
user    0m3.993s
sys 0m0.010s

float c = float(a)*float(b); a 1,000,000,000 times:
real    0m2.815s
user    0m2.764s
sys 0m0.010s
```

Each compiled with `g++ -O0`.

#for_loops

Comment: In other words, you better be doing that multiplication at least this many times for this to make slight difference  (this is most likely some very very premature optimization).

Comment: This should all of course be dependent on the CPU you run this on. I'm currently on `Intel(R) Pentium(R) D CPU 3.40GHz`, but it should be no problem to compile and execute the same for loops on your PC.

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a (possibly premature) micro-optimization to me and as such the only way to know for sure is to profile your specific application. So many other factors could affect the performance, such as the time to convert the double to integer etc.

The only thing I can suggest is that if you don't need doubles until later in the process, do all the initial computation as int, and only convert to double at the last possible minute before you need the double precision.

Answer (score 1):

```
 int(a*b);
```

here you multiply two **doubles**, because conversion is done *after* multiplying (also you convert to int then to double, so you make it more inefficient, plus not accurate)

therefore, the solution is second snippet, because u convert before multiplication

```
 int(a)*int(b)
```

Comment: True.  Is this also the best way to do it, or is there a faster solution?

Comment: Adding comes to my mind, but it would be hard guess becuse modern processors do multiplication faster than previous processors. Also you can use SIMD registers to multiply fast enough floats (available in <DirectXMath.h>).